# Configuring hostname on ubuntu 14.04 returns "unknown instance"

Tags: ubuntu, hostname

I am having trouble understanding the concept of configuring the hostname on Ubuntu 14.04. The machine is configured to run several services like webserver, but also needs to have sendmail running. Therefore I am trying to configure the fqdn via /etc/hosts

```
# IPv4
127.0.0.1 localhost

136.243.84.106 staging.mailserver.mydomain.com mail

# IPv6
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
2a01:4f8:212:27c8::2  fx1
```

then I try to restart hostname:

```
sudo service hostname restart
```

This returns following error message:

```
stop: Unknown instance: 
hostname stop/waiting
```

What is the problem causing this? The configuration looks OK as far as I can tell.

Thank you for any help ont this.

Comment: Check the configuration as suggested by @Neil T and the about restarting service hostname service is now running as upstart services run this command `stop hostname` and `start hostname` now when you enter `hostname` command this should show the hostname

Answer (score 0):

Are you also configuring /etc/hostname?

The server obtains its own name from the /etc/hostname file.  Adding it to /etc/hosts is just so the server can resolve its own hostname.  Speaking of which, you should add whatever you set the hostname to on the 127.0.0.1 line.

So if you set /etc/hostname to 'mail', then change /etc/hosts to have this line:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost mail
```